# Debezium docker-compose-mysql-avro-worker.yaml connector issue: Class io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter could not be found

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am using this official docker compose setup from debezium - [docker-compose-mysql-avro-worker.yaml](https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/blob/main/tutorial/docker-compose-mysql-avro-worker.yaml).

As required - I have started the setup using below -

```
export DEBEZIUM_VERSION=2.0
docker-compose -f docker-compose-mysql-avro-worker.yaml up
```

The container `quay.io/debezium/connect:2.0` is failing to start with below error -

> 11 19:26:03,252 INFO   ||  Added aliases
> 'PrincipalConnectorClientConfigOverridePolicy' and 'Principal' to
> plugin
> 'org.apache.kafka.connect.connector.policy.PrincipalConnectorClientConfigOverridePolicy'
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader]
>
> 2022-12-11 19:26:03,291 ERROR  ||  Stopping due to error
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed]
>
> org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value
> io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter for configuration
> key.converter: Class io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter could not
> be found.
>
> at
> org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseType(ConfigDef.java:744)
>
> at
> org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseValue(ConfigDef.java:490)
>
> at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:483)
>
> at
> org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.(AbstractConfig.java:113)
>
> at
> org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.(AbstractConfig.java:133)
>
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConfig.(WorkerConfig.java:425)
>
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedConfig.(DistributedConfig.java:550)
>
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.startConnect(ConnectDistributed.java:95)
>
> at
> org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:80)

**Any suggestion on how to resolve this issue.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From version 2.0, Confluent Avro converters was removed from Docker image. Here is the ticket https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DBZ-4952

You have to build your own image and add missing jar files.

Comment: are there any steps documented some where on how to build the new image. +1

Comment: ```
# To build the image: docker build -t local/connect:2.0.1.Final
FROM quay.io/debezium/connect:2.0.1.Final
# download your missing jar to  $KAFKA_CONNECT_PLUGINS_DIR
```

Check more here https://github.com/debezium/container-images/blob/main/connect-base/1.9/Dockerfile#L45-L49

Finally change connect image in your docker-compose.yaml

Answer (score 0):

> Class io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter could not be found.

You need to provide this class on the Connect worker classpath, such as by mounting Confluent's `avro-converter` JAR within the container.

Or, the `plugin.path` defined in the Kafka Connect properties is incorrect for discovering this class is available in the container.

Comment: should not the container image be self sufficient with the required jars etc.. I think that what the containers are best at by having all the required libraries with in them. Or atleast should not the docker-compose file should have the required setup.

Comment: Confluent changed their licensing, so no. See other answer

Comment: +1. Then atleast it should be documented and tell users how they should add the avro-connector jar if they have to use the compose file.

Comment: I agree. Open an issue in the github repo